# "FindName" doesn't work if an element added in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-tree

In a WPF app, if a ContentControl is declared in XAML,

```
<Grid Name="MyGrid">
    <ContentControl Name="MyContentControl" />
</Grid>
```

then I can easily reference it in code using `FindName`:

```
ContentControl cc = FindName("MyContentControl") as ContentControl;
cc.Content = ...
```

But if I add the ContentControl in code instead:

```
 ContentControl contentcntr = new ContentControl();
 contentcntr.Name = "MyContentControl";
 this.MyGrid.Children.Add(contentcntr);
```

The `FindName` doesn't find it.

What's wrong with it in the second case? What's the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The XAML parser automatically registers the names in a namescope, if you create elements like this you may need to do that yourself using [`RegisterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.registername.aspx). (There is an [accessor on `FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername.aspx) as well.)